# File Download won't complete (discards finished file, restarts - affecting newer Chrome (-like) browser)

Tags: python, django, django-views

This wasn't a problem until recently and it's only affecting Chrome-like browsers. It does affect Brave, for example, but the download still works well on Firefox. And this problem started on recently.

My server creates a report file (a csv) and this should then, when ready, be served to the user via a link. The report file is created via a asynchronous task via django-celery. If the file is not ready, the page just reloads and offers the same download link. Creating the file doesn't take very long in practice...

It's not particularly sophisticated, but it works for my purposes.

View:

```
def account_get_all(request):
    link = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.GET.get('create-report'):
            # creates report
        elif request.GET.get('link'):
            link = request.GET.get('link')
            try:
                result = AsyncResult(link)
                if result.ready():
                    filename = "path/to/app/media/dumps/" + result.get()
                    wrapper = FileWrapper(open(filename))
                    response = FileResponse(wrapper, content_type='text/plain')
                    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filename)
                    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="'+result.get()+'"'
                    return response
                else:
                    parsed_uri = urlparse(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
                    domain = '{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}/'.format(uri=parsed_uri)
                    return redirect(domain + path + result)
            except:
                # do some error handling
        return render(request, 'get_report.html', {'accounts' : accounts, 'file_link': link })
    else:
        return render(request, 'get_report.html', {'accounts' : accounts })
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have dissected the problem, removed the line `response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filename)`, and it worked...

I googled this and, yes, there are some comments about certain browsers (Chrome and such, obvs!) rejecting a file when it's not exactly the size that it's advertised as. In the comments it said that the file size changed between the size request and the download finishes. But that's not at all my issue here. I do not know why the file size is different from when I get the Content-Length.

I may open another question for this issue.